# ifconfig ethernet (eth0) no data flow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet

Hello this is my ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:46:5d:44:5e:fe  
          inet addr:10.0.0.6  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5246:5dff:fe44:5efe/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1236727 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:1236727 (1.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:97:4a:f0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fe97:4af0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5061 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:9874 (9.8 KB)
```

As you can see there are no packets under eth0. If I try to monitor ethernet activity the graph is not doing anything at all. If I try it with a wifi It work just fine.

The way Im connected to internet is: Router --> switch --> my Ethernet port. Im running Xubuntu 14.04.

edit:

ip route:

```
default via 10.0.0.138 dev eth0  proto static 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.6  metric 1
```

route:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.138      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

I can ping 10.0.0.138

Comment: What are your routes? `ip route` or `route`?

Comment: default via 10.0.0.138 dev eth0  proto static 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.6  metric 1

Comment: It's best to edit your original post and add this sort of information.  Is traffic flowing though? As in, can you ping `10.0.0.138`? (again, add to your original post)

Comment: Have you checked the results of other tools? `ip -s link`, `cat /proc/net/dev`, `netstat -i`. All ran using `sudo`.

Comment: Yes they all give basically the same information as ifconfig

Comment: I can only imagine it's a kernel or driver bug.  I've found [this on AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/422244/network-traffic-reports-as-zero-bytes).  Maybe it's the same problem?

Comment: Yeah must be a driver. I tried to run ifconfig on another two computers and they have an eth1 interfece from which you can monitor network traffic. Thank you very much for your info.

Comment: Check the output of `dmesg` for the eth0 NIC.

Answer (score 3):

OK The solution to this problem was to upgrade the kernel from 3.13 to 3.14.

Many thanks to @garethTheRed for leading me to this solution.

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_all.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-headers-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.1-trusty/linux-image-3.14.1-031401-generic_3.14.1-031401.201404141220_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.14.1-*.deb linux-image-3.14.1-*.deb
sudo reboot
```